# How do I make a textvariable add to a list using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to make a Random Team Generator using tkinter and having problems adding names to a list. I want the Entry function to add the entered names into a list which I later randomize and divide into different chunks. But I simply cant add the entered names into the list.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random

window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Random Team Generator")
window.minsize(600, 400)

names = []


def click_me():
    nmrTeams = teams.get()
    


def addto_list():
    names.append(name)


label = ttk.Label(window, text="Enter the Names: ")
label.place(x=5, y=0)

name = tk.StringVar()
nameEntered = ttk.Entry(window, width=15, textvariable=name)
nameEntered.place(x=7, y=20)


button1 = ttk.Button(window, text="Click to enter Names", command=addto_list())
button1.place(x=6, y=45)

label1 = ttk.Label(window, text='Number of Teams: ')
label1.place(x=5, y=80)

teams = tk.IntVar()
nmbTeams = ttk.Entry(window, width=15, textvariable=teams)
nmbTeams.place(x=7, y=100)

button = ttk.Button(window, text="Generate the Teams", command=click_me)
button.place(x=6, y=125)

label1 = ttk.Label(window, text='Name of the Players: ')
label1.place(x=150, y=0)

print(teams)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `names.append(name.get())`would this fix the issue? also for entries this would work too: `names.append(nameEntered.get())` also I suggest You follow PEP 8 and use `snake_case` for function and variable names

Comment: `command=addto_list()` calls the function *immediately*, and uses its return value (None) as the action to perform when the button is clicked.  Get rid of those parentheses.